# How to store variable value into an array inside a for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to calculate distance between 2 (points) latitudes and longitudes, one point is in an array and other is sent as parameter. The calculated distance should store in another array so that I can calculate minimum distance in an array. The problem is am not able to store that calculated distance into an array so plzz do help me out.

```
 @Override
    public MinimumDistanceModel getMinimumDistance(double latitude, double longitude) throws Exception {
        try {

            double lon1 = longitude;
            double lat1 = latitude;
            List<MinimumDistanceDomain> minDistDomain = minimumDistanceDAO.getFranchiseDetails();
            for(MinimumDistanceDomain minimumDistanceDomain : minDistDomain) {
                double  lat2 = minimumDistanceDomain.getLatitude();
                double lon2 = minimumDistanceDomain.getLongitude();

                MinimumDistanceModel minimumDistanceModel = new MinimumDistanceModel();
                minimumDistanceModel.setDistance1(CommonUtils.distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2));

                System.out.println(minimumDistanceModel.getDistance1());

                Double distance = minimumDistanceModel.getDistance1();

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Exception getMinimumDistance in DistanceServiceImpl" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;

    }
```

`

Result of above code: It's just printing the distances between those 2 points, how do I return those distances in an array

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you need to store things in an array to calculate the minimum? Just keep the minimum you have seen so far in a variable.

Comment: @JoeC i have updated question with current behaviour

Comment: @AndyTurner How to keep the minimum without storing it into an array

Comment: Like Andy mentioned you store it in a variable, the same way you store values in lon1 and lat1

Answer (score 0):

The below code will assign a value for each iteration, basically what I am saying is since you have the lat and long you can do a calc within each iteration to get the distance instead of using common utils . Key line here is this one `testArray[i]=i;`

```
 var lat ; 
    var long; 
    var distance; 
    int[] testDistanceArray = new int[50];

        for (int i = 0; i < testDistanceArray.length; i++) {  
            testDistanceArray[i]= lat -long ;
            distance = testDistanceArray[i]
            // that will give you the distance for each iteration
        }
```